# iam creating login page in asp.net2012 but it is failed please tell me code

Tags: asp.net

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
        If (txtuid.Text = "isol" & txtpwd = "a") Then
            Session("uid") = txtuid.Text
            Response.Redirect("IPDbilling.aspx")
            Return

        Else
            lblmsg.text = "invalide details"
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to ask question on stackoverflow ? If you don't know read it before asking the question

Comment: Posting a code snippet and saying "it is failed" will get you little to no help.  **How** is it failing?  **What** is doing or not doing?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Did you get any errors? Any Exceptions? You have to mention those..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `And` instead of `&`.

```
If (txtuid.Text = "isol" And txtpwd = "a") Then
```

Also, if `txtpwd` is a `TextBox`, you need to use `txtpwd.Text`, not `txtpwd`.

`&` in VB.NET is a concatenation operator for strings:

```
Dim val1 As String = "Hello"
Dim val2 As String = " World!"

Dim val3 As String = val1 & val2
```

val3 will equal "Hello World!"

You can also use `AndAlso` to perform short-circuit evaluation:

```
If (txtuid.Text = "isol" AndAlso txtpwd = "a") Then
```

In this case, if `txtuid.Text` is not equal to "isol" the second part (`txtpwd = "a"`) will not be evaluated, because the first part already failed (was false).

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you have a compilation error and a logical one
compilation:
& should be replaced with AND I'm guessing you're a c#/cpp/c person.

Logic:
 there is no need to Return after Response.Redirect, only one exit
 there is a catch, you can use Response.Redirect(locationString,True)
 that will delay the redirect until you are out of the sub, I dont like it as there is no reason to delay if you control the flow anyway.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
       Dim whereToNext As String

    If (txtuid.Text = "isol" AND txtpwd.Text = "a") Then
        Session("uid") = txtuid.Text
         whereToNext = "IPDbilling.aspx"


    Else
        lblmsg.Text = "invalide details"
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        whereToNext = "login.aspx"
    End If

          Response.Redirect(whereToNext)

End Sub
```

I hope this helps
M

p.s.
when leaving the sub with Response.Redirect will throw a ThreadCancelledException that you can just shrug off. It is thrown because you left the sub in a non clean way.
If you want to leave cleanly use the Response.Redirect(string,True) but use it at the end of your Sub.